# How to get Latitude and Longitude when clicked inside a Poylgon or a GeoJson Layer

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, geojson

I have searched the whole web but couldn't find the solution to it. I dint get it why its so difficult to find the answer.

I'm currently using GeoJson for layering GoogleMaps. Actually I want to set a maker on the layer where the user taps on it and show the layer at the time of clicking on it.

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setOnPolygonClickListener(this);

    try {
        final GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(mMap, R.raw.map,
                getApplicationContext());

        layer.addLayerToMap();
        GeoJsonPolygonStyle polygonStyle=layer.getDefaultPolygonStyle();
        polygonStyle.setFillColor(0x00ffffff);
        polygonStyle.setStrokeWidth(0f);

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                try {
                    //Log.e("SahajLOG", " latlang > " + latLng + " " + layer.getBoundingBox().contains(latLng) + " " + layer.getBoundingBox().including(latLng));
                    if (hashMapMarker != null) {
                        if (hashMapMarker.get("otherLocMark") != null) {
                            removeUpMaker("otherLocMark");
                            setUpMaker(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, "otherLocMark", "locationMarked");
                        } else
                            setUpMaker(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, "otherLocMark", "locationMarked");
                    } else
                        setUpMaker(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, "otherLocMark", "locationMarked");

                    // Get the bounding box builder.


                    LatLngBounds bbc = getLatLngBoundingBox(layer);
                    if (bbc.contains(latLng)) {
                        layer.removeLayerFromMap();
                        GeoJsonPolygonStyle polygonStyle=layer.getDefaultPolygonStyle();
                        polygonStyle.setFillColor(0x32e74c3c);
                        polygonStyle.setStrokeWidth(1.5f);
                        layer.addLayerToMap();
                    } else {
                        layer.removeLayerFromMap();
                        GeoJsonPolygonStyle polygonStyle=layer.getDefaultPolygonStyle();
                        polygonStyle.setFillColor(0x00ffffff);
                        polygonStyle.setStrokeWidth(0f);
                        layer.addLayerToMap();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        /*layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new Layer.OnFeatureClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFeatureClick(Feature feature) {
                Log.e("SahajLOG", " feature > " + feature);
            }
        });*/

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Do other setup activities here too, as described elsewhere in this tutorial.
    // Turn on the My Location layer and the related control on the map.
    updateLocationUI();

    // Get the current location of the device and set the position of the map.
   // getDeviceLocation();
}


@Override
public void onPolygonClick(Polygon polygon) {
    Log.e("SahajLOG", "Polygon click "+polygon.getPoints());
    polygon.setFillColor(0x32e74c3c);
    polygon.setStrokeWidth(1.5f);
}
```

**So, I want the Lat and Long where it is tapped when user clicks on polygon.**

Comment: you found any solution?

Comment: actually you couldn't determine the exact lat,lang on clicked area. So, as a workaround i used small polygons and marked the lat,lang in center of polygon. And if you come up with other solution please mention it. Thanks!.